# Recursively read directories and selectively get contents

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out the best way to pull out the contents of all directories called "thumbs" from within a parent directory. It looks like using DirectoryIterator is a better approach than scandir, although I'm not 100% sure. I'm basically trying to grab all thumbnails from within a gallery, so I want to ignore any directories which aren't named "thumbs". Can anyone advise the best way to go about this? Many thanks

Comment: There's a RecursiveDirectoryIterator (http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator), if you've got multiple levels of directories, each of which could contain a thumbs subdir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) or the appropriate partner [`getBasename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getbasename.php) in [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) if you want to use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`:

```
$path = 'some non-specific named directory path';
$dirName = basename($path);
if ('thumbs' === $dirName)
{
   # found a thumbs directory in $path
}
```